Word for a person who researches everything with full details, to learn all information about a subject going back to its existence
What's a word or words to describe a person who researches everything with full details,  to learn all information about a subject going back to its existence? For example I'm researching about one Pacific fish and I end up researching every single fact known to mankind.

Leading expert, world's expert, mavin, researcher?

A walking encyclopedia on the Australian anchovy?

Or: the authority on the needlespine coral goby.

@YosefBaskin "Leading expert" means that other people call on the person for their expertise. It has nothing to do with how they gathered that expertise -- they could have originated it, rather than researched it. Also, someone could do all that reserach and still not become the resource.

I believe you're looking to define someone who strives to learn everything about a specific subject, rather than someone who possesses that knowledge. Supercurious, perhaps? If there is obsession on a single subject, monomaniac is an option as a noun.  Further clarification and an example sentence would help.

One word that might fit the kind of person you're asking about is polymath, which Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) defines as "a person of encyclopedic learning." Of course, a polymath doesn't just research every subject; he or she actually masters the content of every subject.

researching something, not about something. going back to its beginning.

I think polymath usually is someone who excels at many subjects, not one. Von Neumann, for example. The above example talks about someone knowing one subject inside out.

Can you first clarify '… going back to its existence…'? Does that mean '… going back to its origin…' or what, please?

You could call that person an exhaustive researcher:

exhaustive adjective
2.a. Characterized by exhausting a subject, etc.; leaving no part unexamined or unconsidered; complete, comprehensive. 1786–
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

You can find examples of the phrase exhaustive researcher at Google Books.

It seems to be at least a weak collocation; there are quite a few hits in a Google search. (I almost always downvote free combinations, ie phrases below even weak collocation cohesiveness.)

@EdwinAshworth — exhaustive research is a decent collocation, right? Just a skip and a jump to exhaustive researcher...

Mobile phoner? Common senser? Post officer?

@EdwinAshworth — I suppose we’ll need post officers to monitor our mail-in ballots.

Consummate (adj.) could work.

complete or perfect; supremely skilled; superb

a consummate master of the violin.
[Dictionary.com]

"Buff", as in "an X__fish buff".
Common terms, used in their most common sentences, include: "He is a history buff." "He is a [U.S.] Civil War buff."
